# JTAG for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: jtag

I'm working on my extension hat for Raspberry Pi 3. I would like to add a SWD/JTAG among all of the additional features. Have you ever dealt with this issue? How can I implement this? I mean, it's not meant to be a 6-pin header only. It's meant to be a whole hardware (microcontrollers, capacitors, resistors etc.). It should be ready to use by using a USB cable only. Can you recommend any ideas?

Comment: Apparently, the JTAG pins are brought to the GPIO extension connector. See https://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/raspberry/jtagsetup/. See also https://www.suse.com/c/debugging-raspberry-pi-3-with-jtag/. So, it should be easy. What is your specific concern?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think I start to understand. You don't want the hat to actually expose a JTAG connector. You want it to include the whole USB to JTAG debugger hardware, usually found in probes, right? Well, I'm sure there are plenty of open source JTAG (using various chips, like FTDI or small MCUs) you could base your own design on.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know that RPi has the JTAG pins. I want to have a JTAG on my board. I don't want to use a Segger J-Link or something. I mean something like this http://www.usbjtag.com/image/jtagntmedia/usbjtagntbd.jpg. Of course it is separate device. I want to have something like this on my board and use only USB cable.

Comment: Then, replicate some open source JTAG probe hardware on your own board. Most of them are based on FTDI chips: e.g. https://randomprojects.org/wiki/Floss-JTAG, or http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Blaster, but some of them are based on custom firmwares with general-purpose MCUs: e.g. https://github.com/blacksphere/blackmagic/wiki

Comment: I've just checked your links. I'm using the RPi3 and Blackmagic do not support this platform at present. Floss-JTAG seems to be ok.